# Appending Checkbox Value jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a created a function to alert the user all the values they have checked from the checkboxes. For example if the user selects '1' and '2' then it should alert '1, 2' or if the user select '1' and '3' it should alert 1, 3 etc. However, it is not working. Any help would be appreciated :)

```
<form>
  <input class="1" type="checkbox" name="1" value="1" onclick="add()">1
  <input class="2" type="checkbox" name="2" value="2" onclick="add()">2
  <input class="3" type="checkbox" name="3" value="3" onclick="add()">3
  <input class="4" type="checkbox" name="4" value="4" onclick="add()">4
</form>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/7r93feke/)

Comment: You should probably add some *javascript* to a *javascript*-tagged question. I know it's in the Fiddle, but you need to also include it in your post.

Comment: You're using an event listener inside a function that called on `onClick`. Or I'm missing here something or something went wrong?

Comment: Sorry, the JSfiddle shouldn't have the click function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
    var chkd = $('input:checkbox:checked');
    if( chkd.length == 2 ) {
        var vals = chkd.map(function() {
            return this.value;
        })
        .get().join(', ');
        alert( vals );
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input class="1" type="checkbox" name="1" value="1"/>1
  <input class="2" type="checkbox" name="2" value="2"/>2
  <input class="3" type="checkbox" name="3" value="3"/>3
  <input class="4" type="checkbox" name="4" value="4"/>4
</form>
```

**UPDATE**

```
$(function() {
    $('#myButton').on('click', function() {
        var text = $('input[name=somename]').val();
        var chkd = $('input:checkbox:checked');
        var vals = chkd.map(function() {
            return this.value;
         })
        .get().join(', ');
        alert("Name: " + text + "\n" + "Checkbox: " + vals );
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/9gsuck2m/1/)

Comment: Glad you found this helpful :-) Enjoy!

Comment: Also, how do I apply this function to an alert()? This code was a sample one that I am doing. The project I am working on is displaying multiple values in the alert(). At the moment it is looking like this
`alert( "Name: " + name + "\n" + "Add: " +  add() )`
But it runs the add() function and then the alert() and the 'Add:' is undefined. I hope this makes sense :)

Comment: Have you played with my demo? You probably need to replace add() with vals. If not, please create a demo that should clarify you intent.

Comment: Yeah, I have. Ok, I'll try that if it doesn't work I'll create a demo. Thanks.

Comment: I guess you already know that I'm not a fun of *inline js*. So I have re-code the demo -- https://jsfiddle.net/9gsuck2m/1/

Answer (score 2):

You could just do like below.

```
$(':checkbox').click(function() {
    alert($(':checkbox:checked').map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).get());
});
```

**[The demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/7r93feke/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

```js
function add() {
  var checked = '';
  $(':checked').each(function() {
    checked += $(this).val() + ',';
  });
  console.log(checked);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="1" type="checkbox" name="1" value="1" onclick="add()">1
<input class="2" type="checkbox" name="2" value="2" onclick="add()">2
<input class="3" type="checkbox" name="3" value="3" onclick="add()">3
<input class="4" type="checkbox" name="4" value="4" onclick="add()">4
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way is this:

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
  $(':checked').each(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="footboard" type="checkbox" name="1" value="1">1
<input class="drawers" type="checkbox" name="2" value="2">2
<input class="casters" type="checkbox" name="3" value="3">3
<input class="squeak" type="checkbox" name="4" value="4">4
```